# Using an onclick function to turn on and off images using id and classes, as well as generating and updating list items with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using an onclick function to turn on and off images, I have the images set with with "id", and that's how I've been turning them on and off. However I have 3 sets of images that need to be in a "class". I would like to keep everything within on function. So as not to have two "onclick functions". I'm also having trouble increasing and decreasing the values of the images that will be in the class. So the idea is, as you click on image, the image dynamically will generate a list item. and when clicking on the image again(turn of the image) and remove the list item. I having trouble doing this with the class items, as that list item needs to be updated everytime an item of the same class is clicked.

if this helps: https://c9.io/laurenashley/lauren_17_ootpik_hardware
I can grant you access....

This is all of the images that are being turned on and off. There are two station builders..

This is station one:
    <

```
div id="station-builder">
                           <!--visible at all times-->
                            <img id="touchscreen"   src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/touchscreen.png" alt="Touchscreen" title="Touchscreen"/>
                            <img id="macmini"       src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/macmini.png" alt="Mac mini" title="Mac mini"/> 
                            <!--hidden items-->
                            <img id="cashDrawer"    class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/cashDrawer_grey.png"     alt="Cash Drawer" title="Cash Drawer"/>
                            <img id="storageDrawer" class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/storageDrawer_grey.png"  alt="Cash Drawer with Storage" title="Cash Drawer with Storage"/>
                            <img id="keyboard"      class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/keyboard_grey.png" alt="Keyboard" title="Keyboard"/>
                            <img id="mouse"         class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/mouse_grey.png"    alt="Mouse" title="Mouse"/>
                            <img class="printer"       class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/printer_grey.png"  alt="Receipt Printer" title="Receipt Printer"/>

                            <img id="singleBar"     class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/singleBar_grey.png"   alt="Single-line Barcode Scanner" title="Single-line Barcode Scanner"/>
                            <img id="multiBar"      class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/multiBar_grey.png"    alt="Multip-line Barcode Scanner" title="Multip-line Barcode Scanner"/>  

                            <img id="scale"         class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/scale_grey.png"    alt="WeighScale" title="WeighScale"/> 
                            <img id="display"       class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/display_grey.png"  alt="Customer Display" title="Customer Display"/> 
                        </div> <!--end of station-builder-->
This is station two        
                        <div id="station-builder-2">
                            <!--hidden items-->
                            <img class="printer"       class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/printer2_grey.png"  alt="Receipt Printer2" title="Kitchen/Bar/Expo/ printer"/>
                            <img class="printer"       class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/printer3_grey.png"  alt="Receipt Printer3" title="Kitchen/Bar/Expo/ printer2"/>

                            <img class="ipadmini"       class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/ipadmini_grey.png"  alt="iPad_mini" title="iPad mini" />
                            <img class="ipadmini"      class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/ipadmini2_grey.png"  alt="iPad_mini" title="iPad mini2"/>

                            <img class="mobilePrinter"   class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/mobilePrinter_grey.png"  alt="Mobile Printer" title="Mobile Printer"/>
                            <img class="mobilePrinter"  class="part" src="images/placeholder/get_hardware/mobilePrinter2_grey.png"  alt="Mobile Printer2" title="Mobile Printer2"/>
                        </div> <!--end of station-builder-->

    <ul id="list"></ul>
```

Here is the start of the javascript:
//JS FOR HARDWARE SECTION

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".part").mouseover(function () {
    if (this.className !== 'part selected') {
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/placeholder/get_hardware/' + this.id + '.png');
    }
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
      if (this.className !== 'part selected') {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/placeholder/get_hardware/' + this.id + '_grey.png');
      }
    });
  });
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  $(".part").click(function () {
    if (this.className == 'part') {
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/placeholder/get_hardware/' + this.id + '.png');
      console.log(this);
      if (this.id == 'keyboard') {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        //li.setAttribute("alt","keyboard_li");
        li.setAttribute("id", "keyboard_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Keyboard'));
        list.appendChild(li);
        //$(".tooltip").show();
      }
      if (this.id == 'mouse') {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("id", "mouse_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Mouse'));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.class == 'printer') {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "printer_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Receipt Printer"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.class == "printer") {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "printer_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Receipt Printer"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.class == "printer") {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "printer_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Receipt Printer"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.id == 'scale') {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("id", "scale_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Weighscale"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.id == 'display') {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("id", "display_li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Customer Display"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
      if (this.class == "ipadmini") {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "ipad_mini");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("iPad mini"));
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
    } else {
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/placeholder/get_hardware/' + this.id + '_grey.png');
      console.log(this);
      if (this.id == 'multiBar') {
        $(".tooltip").hide();
      }
      if (this.id == "keyboard") {
        $("#keyboard_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.id == "mouse") {
        $("#mouse_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.class == "printer") {
        $("#printer_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.class == "printer") {
        $("#printer_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.class == "printer") {
        $("#printer_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.id == "scale") {
        $("#scale_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.id == "display") {
        $("#display_li").remove();
      }
      if (this.class == "ipadmini") {
        $("ipadi_mini").remove();
      }
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, you can have id and class in the same element.

Comment: yeah, but how would that work with               :$(".part").click(function () {
    if (this.className == 'part') {
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/placeholder/get_hardware/' + this.id + '.png');

Comment: The code I have above works, with the id attributes, It's getting to work with the class attributes

Comment: From looking at your image codes. You have two attributes with the name "class" make one class and the other id. When you check just do something like `this.id == 'printer'`

Comment: i had that before and it worked, however, I'm running into the issue, with updating the list values while using id's. Being as id's are meant to be unique. Currently right now, each element(img) that you click on has a value of one. When you click on the image again, it removes the list item... Does this kinda make for sense?

Comment: so I have a three of the same printer images...and when one is clicked on it dynamically generates a list item. When a second printer image is clicked, it should update the list item to say "2 printers". I'm not sure how to do with id(s)...

Comment: does anyone have insight for this logic problem I'm having?